# How to aggregate over date including all prior dates

Tags: sql, group-by, delta-lake

I am working with a table in Databricks Delta lake. It gets new records appended every month. The field `insert_dt` indicates when the records are inserted.

```
| ID | Mrc | insert_dt  |
|----|-----|------------|
| 1  | 40  | 2022-01-01 |
| 2  | 30  | 2022-01-01 |
| 3  | 50  | 2022-01-01 |
| 4  | 20  | 2022-02-01 |
| 5  | 45  | 2022-02-01 |
| 6  | 55  | 2022-03-01 |
```

Now I want to aggregate by `insert_dt` and calculate the average of `Mrc`. For each date, the average is done not just for the records of that date but all records with date prior to that. In this example, there are 3 rows for 2022-01-01, 5 rows for 2022-02-01 and 6 rows for 2022-03-01. The expected results would look like this:

```
| Mrc | insert_dt  |
|-----|------------|
| 40  | 2022-01-01 |
| 37  | 2022-02-01 |
| 40  | 2022-03-01 |
```

How do I write a query to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the documentation for Delta-lake databricks (https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-window-functions.html ) and it looks like TSQL so I think this will work for you, but you may need to tweak slightly.

The approach is to condense each day to a single point and then use window functions to get the running totals. Note that any given day may have a different count, so you can't just average the averages.

```
--Enter the sample data you gave as a CTE for testing
;with cteSample as ( 
    SELECT * FROM ( VALUES 
        (1, 40, CONVERT(date,'2022-01-01'))
        , ('2', '30', '2022-01-01')
        , ('3', '50', '2022-01-01')
        , ('4', '20', '2022-02-01')
        , ('5', '45', '2022-02-01')
        , ('6', '55', '2022-03-01')
    ) as TabA(ID, Mrc, insert_dt) 
)--Solution begins here, find the total and count for each date 
--because window can only handle a single "last row"
, cteGrouped as (
    SELECT insert_dt, SUM(Mrc) as MRCSum, COUNT(*) as MRCCount
    FROM cteSample
    GROUP BY insert_dt
)--Now use the window function to get the totals "up to today"
, cteTotals as ( 
    SELECT insert_dt
        , SUM(MRCSum) OVER (ORDER BY insert_dt RANGE 
            BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MrcSum
        , SUM(MRCCount) OVER (ORDER BY insert_dt RANGE 
            BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MrcCount
    FROM    cteGrouped as G
) --Now divide out to get the average to date
SELECT insert_dt, MrcSum/MrcCount as MRCAverage
FROM cteTotals as T
```

This gives the following output

| insert_dt | MRCAverage |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 40 |
| 2022-02-01 | 37 |
| 2022-03-01 | 40 |

Answer (score 2):

Calculate a running average using a window function (the inner subquery) and then pick only one row per `insert_dt` - the one with the highest `id`. I only tested this on PostgreSQL 13 so not sure how far does delta-lake support the SQL standard and will it work there or not though.

```sql
select mrc, insert_dt from 
(
 select avg(mrc) over (order by insert_dt, id) mrc, insert_dt, 
        row_number() over (partition by insert_dt order by id desc) rn
 from the_table
) t
where rn = 1
order by insert_dt;
```

DB-fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k5N5hAMcUJbn3kt6h2HAAL/0)

**Update** If `the_table` has no `id` column then use a CTE to add one.

```sql
with t_id as (select *, row_number() over (order by insert_dt) id from the_table)
select mrc, insert_dt from 
(
 select avg(mrc) over (order by insert_dt, id) mrc, insert_dt, 
        row_number() over (partition by insert_dt order by id desc) rn
 from t_id 
) t
where rn = 1
order by insert_dt;
```

Comment: This works in delta. What if there is no ID field or any type of identifier column? What needs to be order by together with `insert_dt`?

Comment: Well, you need an id so use a CTE. See updated answer.